# Select element class dependent on its other class

Tags: css, css-selectors

i made some mistakes and need to know if can solve it :(

look to this html

```
  <style>
    .error { width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block; }
    /* This is icon class */
  </style>

  <div class="error"> this Is error icon 32px * 32px </div>

  <div class="error"> this Is error notice  500px * 35px </div>
```

**How can i make it effect the first error class and don't effect the second**

***i did this***

```
  <style>
     .error[class*='icon'] { width:32px; height:32px; display:inline-block; }
      /* i was think it should effect the first class only but not ???  */
  </style>

  <div class="icon error"> this Is error icon 32px * 32px </div>

  <div class="notice error"> this Is error notice  500px * 35px </div>
```

**Is there is other way
  i used**  `.error[class*='icon']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.error.icon` instead of `.error[class*='icon']`, although I don't know how your attribute selector could possibly affect your second `.error` element.

Or if you don't want to add the extra classes you can use `.error:first-child` instead, assuming there aren't any other sibling elements around in the same container element.

Comment: Thank you @BoltClock  It work , may be i'm sleepy , its easy answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`div.icon.error` is the most precise way to do it